# SAP Crystal Reports, version for VS 2010 installer issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, crystal-reports

I've recently downloaded the installer for Crystal Reports version for VS 2010. I'm able to install it on my PC no problem. But the area I need help in is installing it on a drive that isn't the C drive.

I'm trying to install it on the PC's D drive so that it can be accessed from other computers. But when I run the installation, it only allows it to be installed on the C drive.

There is a browse button to chose a different path. But the button is not enabled, there for giving me no choice.

Does anyone know how I could enable the browse button, or if there is a better download that gives me the path choice?

I downloaded the installer from http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/us2_default.asp.

Comment: What do you mean by "so that it can be accessed from other computers." - It sounds like you *really* want to install it on several PCs...

Comment: The program we are using that needs this is running from the D drive so that it can be accessed from any PC on the network. I was hoping to install CR on that drive so we wouldn't need to install it multiple times. I just assumed that would work. Despite all the warnings of assuming.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports will need to be installed on each PC anyway (I believe it registers some COM components, registry, etc.) so even if you could change the installation path, it wouldn't save you any time/diskspace/etc.